# Error with the following code

Tags: scheme, racket

When I do (visit-doctor suppertime) for this code:

```
(define (visit-doctor name)
  (if (equal? name 'suppertime) (end-session)
  ((write-line (list 'hello name))
  (write-line '(what seems to be the trouble?))
  (doctor-driver-loop name initial-earlier-response))))

(define (end-session) (write-line '(the doctor is done seeing patients today)))
```

it gives me this error:

application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: #
  arguments...:
   #
   #

Comment: If you use DrRacket, do you see a red highlight corresponding to where Racket thinks the error might be located?  I see a problem on the line `((write-line (list 'hello name))`: to me, it looks like a double-function application, where you probably meant to do a single application.  For this specific case, DrRacket **should** be giving you a precise location for this error.  Are you seeing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to use brackets for grouping a block of code.
Scheme doesn't do that.

Your `else` branch is

```
((write-line (list 'hello name))
 (write-line '(what seems to be the trouble?))
 (doctor-driver-loop name initial-earlier-response))
```

which is a list of three elements.

The first element of that list is expected to a procedure, which is then applied to the other two elements, but when you evaluate `(write-line (list 'hello name))` you don't get a procedure, you get `#<void>`.

The fix is to sequence it using `begin`:

```
(begin (write-line (list 'hello name))
       (write-line '(what seems to be the trouble?))
       (doctor-driver-loop name initial-earlier-response))
```